# textbox can't grab text property from findControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I'm using the CreateUserWizardControl in ASP and want to write some data from the registration form into a table of my own. I want to do so at the moment the user is created.

When I debug, the problem with this seems to be that in this line the textbox t I declared in the line before doesn't grab the UserName textbox. It does find something, because it's not null, but the text-property of t is an empty string :

```
t = (TextBox)(this.CreateUserWizard1.FindControl("UserName"));
```

At the next line an exception is thrown: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
o.organisation_name = t.Text;
```

Below is my complete code behind file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;

public partial class registreer : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        BLLorganisation BLLo = new BLLorganisation();
        Organisation o = new Organisation();
        TextBox t = new TextBox();
        t = (TextBox)(this.CreateUserWizard1.FindControl("UserName"));
        o.organisation_name = t.Text;
        o.fk_user_id = (Guid)(Membership.GetUser(CreateUserWizard1.UserName).ProviderUserKey);
        BLLo.insertOneOrganisation(o);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        feedback.InnerHtml = ex.Message;
        feedback.Style.Add("display", "block");
    }
}
}
```

And here is my control in markup:

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" 
            oncreateduser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser">
            <WizardSteps>
                <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server" 
                    Title="Registreer uw organisatie">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                    <h1>Registreer uw organisatie</h1></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Naam van de organisatie:</asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                        ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="Vul de naam van uw organisatie in." 
                                        ToolTip="Vul de naam van uw organisatie in." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

Does anyone has an idea about what is going wrong? Let me know if you need to see more code!

Comment: Obviously there is no control named UserName in CreateUserWizard1. Can you share the markup for textbox UserName?

Comment: Does this help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.username.aspx

Comment: Isn't `CreateUserWizard1.UserName` the value of the `UserName` textbox?

Comment: @HenkMollema, I tried replacing the `o.organisation_name = t.Text;` with `o.organisation_name = (String)(Membership.GetUser(CreateUserWizard1.UserName).UserName);` and now I don't get the exception anymore! That's a step ahead, a big thanks to you!

Now I do get a `Sequence contains no elements` exception at the last line of my try-branch...

Comment: Just `CreateUserWizard1.UserName` should be enough. No need to get the username of a user by its username. Correct me if I'm wrong though. And could you update your question with your new code, so we can take a look at your new error?

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBox t = (TextBox)  CreateUserWizard1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName");
if(t!=null)
   o.organisation_name = t.Text;
```